# We couldn’t get your developer license for Windows 8.1, error 0x80245006

Tags: visual-studio, windows-store-apps

So I want to work on my Win RT app, but I get this error message:

[image]

I have been working on this project for months. Why would it suddenly appear and how should I fix this?

Comment: Lots and lots of Google hits for "0x80245006".  You'll need to get your machine fixed, focus on networking, anti-malware, firewall, proxy or anything else that could interfere with your machine talking to a Microsoft machine across the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Firewall proxy server was blocking the renewal. When it was disabled the renewal worked.